# Definite integral gets stuck in the calculation

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, parallelization

$f=\frac{\sinh ^{-1}\left(e^{-2 k t} \sinh (6 k)\right)}{2 k}-2$

for $k=20$ I have:

$\frac{df}{dt}=-\frac{e^{-20 t} \sinh (60)}{\sqrt{e^{-40 t} \sinh ^2(60)+1}}$

```
f = -2 + ArcSinh[E^(-2 k t) Sinh[6 k]]/(2 k)

Integrate[D[f, t], {t, 0, 10}]
```

And he just gets stuck and doesn't move on. Then I tried to apply parallel computation, but got the error:

```
Needs["Parallel`Developer`"]

f = -2 + ArcSinh[E^(-2 k t) Sinh[6 k]]/(2 k)

Integrate[D[f, t], {t, 0, 10}]

Parallelize::nopar1: \!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(\[Integral]\), \(0\), \(10\)]\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(t\)]f \[DifferentialD]t\)\) cannot be parallelized; proceeding with sequential evaluation.
```

I would be grateful for help in finding out the reason.

Processor AMD Ryzen 7 2700 Pro, 16 Gb RAM. When calculating this task, the processor is loaded by 8-10%.

Comment: Try 'NIntegrate'.

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk
It worked very quickly, but why is this happening?

Comment: This seems to work. `Integrate[D[f, t], {t, 0, 10}, Assumptions -> k > 0]

(-Log[(-1 + E^(12 k) - 
    E^(6 k) Sqrt[-2 + E^(-12 k) + E^(12 k) + 4 E^(40 k)])/(-1 + E^(
    12 k) + E^(6 k) Sqrt[-2 + E^(-12 k) + E^(12 k) + 4 E^(40 k)])] + 
 Log[-Cosh[12 k] + Sinh[12 k]])/(4 k)`

Comment: Yes, it work. Thank you!

Comment: MMA version 12.1. It works and gives a result with conditions.

Comment: In 12.2 `Integrate[D[f, t], t]` produces a wrong answer `(E^(-2 k t)
    ArcTanh[(Sqrt[-1 + 2 E^(4 k t) + Cosh[12 k]] Csch[6 k])/Sqrt[
    2]] Sqrt[-1 + 2 E^(4 k t) + Cosh[12 k]])/(2 k Sqrt[
   2 + 2 E^(-4 k t) Sinh[6 k]^2])`. Did you report a bug to Wolfram Technical Support?

Comment: `Re[(E^(-2 k t) ArcTanh[(Sqrt[-1 + 2 E^(4 k t) + Cosh[12 k]] Csch[
         6 k])/Sqrt[2]] Sqrt[-1 + 2 E^(4 k t) + 
      Cosh[12 k]])/(2 k Sqrt[2 + 2 E^(-4 k t) Sinh[6 k]^2])]` is a right answer. It should be noticed that `Im[(E^(-2 k t) ArcTanh[(Sqrt[-1 + 2 E^(4 k t) + Cosh[12 k]] Csch[
         6 k])/Sqrt[2]] Sqrt[-1 + 2 E^(4 k t) + 
      Cosh[12 k]])/(2 k Sqrt[2 + 2 E^(-4 k t) Sinh[6 k]^2])]` is not a constant.

Comment: Not a bug: the above expression is a constant for each fixed `k`.